# Why django import export is not working in my django project?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am working in django project and I want admin to import data from excel file to database of model Entry.
But it is not working properly .
here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Entry
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin
from .resources import EntryResource

class EntryAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = EntryResource 

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

the error is :
Cannot assign "'vijay'": "Entry.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.

my csv file:

```
Id,User,Member,Member Id,Email Address,State,K No,Board,Last Date,Amount
vijay,team,team54f4d,teamcarbon006@gmail.com,rajasthan,5f4d5f4d,jval,
2022-03-13,54451
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use the user id it's a foreignkey field so do it's returning the error

```
Id,User,Member,Member Id,Email Address,State,K No,Board,Last Date,Amount 1,team,team54f4d,teamcarbon006@gmail.com,rajasthan,5f4d5f4d,jval,2022-03-13,54451
```